# AngelScript code parser - which way should I take?

Tags: c++, parsing, syntax-checking

I'm writing the AngelScript IDE. Now I'm making my own "intellisense" system. I need to parse script file and create tables of functions, variables with their nesting levels etc. Which way should I go? Can System.CodeDom stuff can be used to handle it or is there any working library for that purpose (clang?). If not, please give me names of the algorithms which can be used to obtain information which I want from the script file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in this language implementation kit:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony_(framework)

http://irony.codeplex.com/